# how to convert 2022/02/01 12:56:15 this into 1-feb-2022 IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have start_tsp as value 2022/02/01 12:56:15 and it's datatype is varchar and i want to convert this into 1-FEB-22 in oracle. so, wt will be the syntax for this one.

```
SELECT to_date(start_tsp ,'YYYY/MM/DD')
FROM ETL_CONTROL.ETL_PARAMETERS
```

I tried this one but it getting error

> 'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
> expected'

Comment: Don't store date/time data in varchar columns. Use proper date/time data types.

Comment: Your question is wrong. It should be rather "I want to convert this into `DATE` in Oracle". Converting it into `1-FEB-22` is even worse what you already have.

Comment: The code you've shown won't give that error for your sample string value; it will give "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string" (see RiggsFolly's comment for why). If you are getting ORA-01858 then you have string values in that column that are not in the format you described (which is one of the reasons you should not store dates/times as strings); or (perhaps) they aren't strings at all, but are actually dates/timestamps and you're getting the error because of implicit conversion. Please edit the question to show the table DDL and sample data.

Answer (score 2):

First you'll have to convert it to `DATE`, and then back to `CHAR` using appropriate format mask:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select    to_date('2022/02/01 12:56:15', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')                 as date_value,
  2    to_char(to_date('2022/02/01 12:56:15', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'dd-mon-yyyy') as char_value
  3  from dual;

DATE_VALUE          CHAR_VALUE
------------------- -----------
01.02.2022 12:56:15 01-feb-2022

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to convert it into date and then convert into to char to get desired result.

```
           SELECT 
           to_char(to_date(start_tsp  , 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),'DD-MON-YY') dt 
           FROM ETL_CONTROL.ETL_PARAMETERS ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).